# Is there a generic dag/task can be written in Airflow?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, airflow, airflow-scheduler

Detailed question: I have a scenario in my mind, and would like to take a suggestion from experts!
[image]

in the attached image, first set of image shows current workflow. below is the expected workflow. I can't combine all the workflows into one dag due to different source data refresh time.

I was thinking like, is it possible to create one dag named generic and use the individual tasks in other child dags like templates?

or, how can i call these generic dags from my child dags?

looking for your valuable suggestion to make the work flow optimised and easy to maintain when any update needed in extract and load part. as of now, its really complex as I need to touch all the 4 dags individually!